# CSS full viewport grid with squared items and no overflow

Tags: css, viewport-units

How would I be achieve a layout that:

- occupies the full viewport and not overflow despite the number of items
- items are squared
- grid is vertically and horizontally centered on page

[image: example of layout for clarity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something like this you trying to do? In this case, you need to define the percentage of the height/width of the items, depending on the quantity.

```css
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
  } 
  
  .container {
   align-items:center;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   height:100vh;
   width:100vw; 
  }
  
  .content {
   align-items:center;
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   height:100vw;
   justify-content:center;
   margin:auto;
   width:100vw; 
  }
  
  .item {
   border:1px solid #AAA;
   height:calc(20% - 4px);
      margin:1px;
   width:calc(20% - 4px);
  }
  
  @media (orientation:landscape) {
   .content {
      height:100vh;
      width:100vh;
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="content">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. That's pretty close. It's just missing being squared grid items. Care to elaborate a bit more? Thanks again and in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that, I edited the answer to make the items square.